# How to save a Bitmap as a PNG File with transparency

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I'm working on an Android App written in Kotlin. I need a function that takes a Bitmap and saves it as a PNG File in a variable path because I need a mask. The problem is that my current code doesn't seem to have transparency. If I set my bitmap to an ImageView it has a transparent background, but when I see the created File it's black

This is how I mask the original Bitmap:

```
    private fun maskImage(points: List<PointF>, bitmap: Bitmap){
        val maskedBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(maskedBitmap)

        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        paint.color = Color.TRANSPARENT
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

        //Create the path and set the starting point
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y)

        for (point in points){
            Log.i("Point", "$point.x}, ${point.y}")
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y)
        }

        path.close()
        path.fillType = Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

        imageBitmap.value = maskedBitmap
        val maskFile = fileFromBitmap(maskedBitmap)
    }
```

And this is my failed solution:

```
    private fun fileFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): File?{
        return try {
            val maskFile = File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/AppName",            "mask.png")
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(maskFile)
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
            //outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
            Log.e("Status", "Mask saved successfully")
            maskFile
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("Status", "Save file error!")
            null
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you seeing the file?  BEcause if you're just opening it in a viewer, the background of your viewer may be black

Comment: Because the Gallery app has a black background, copy your output image to your PC and you will see if it's transparent or not

Comment: My viewer background is white

Comment: Does `bitmap.hasAlpha()` return `true` or `false`, please try it

Comment: It returned false. If I use setHasAlpha(true) it works! Thank you